# let puppet install packages from a specific repository

Tags: puppet, apt, dpkg, aptitude

is there a way to tell puppet to install a package from a specific repository?
I'd like to do something like 'aptitude -t testing install vim' in puppet.

The reason why I want to do this is that I want to install specific packages from debian 'testing' repository, but by default only use 'stable'.

Currently I have the 'testing' repository pinned with a priority of -10, so apt won't install packages from it without me explicitly telling it to do so:

```
Package: *                                                                                                                                                                                             
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 990 

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: -10
```

I'm using puppet 2.6.2 on debian-based systems.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question you asked, but what we do is add additional files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` to pin the packages we want to install from testing to that release.  This has the nice benefit of also affecting manual `apt-get` installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [puppetlabs-apt](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt) module and use [apt::force](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt#aptforce)